# Mongoid: how use a custom field instad of _type for inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, mongoid

I'm using ruby on rails 3 with mongoid. I have a class called User with an attribute "type" that determines the user type ("reseller", "account", "distributor"...). I would like to convert these implicit types in an explicit inheritance, maintaining the compatibility with the previous implementation (the new and the old application will use the same database for some time).

So I guess that I need a way to set a custom field as the _type mongoid field for inheritance. But can't fid how :(

Some ideas?

Comment: I have a similar problem, just posted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658755/tell-mongoid-to-use-another-field-other-than-type-to-handle-inheritance), something like a way to use a custom field instead of `_type` for inheritance would really do the trick for me, did you find a way to achieve it @Pablo?